# Need a regex for ONLY Alphanumeric (no pure numbers or letters) AND limit to exactly 10 characters?

Tags: regex

I've run into some issues with this one and cannot find it in past questions.

Criteria:

1. Reject pure digits
2. Reject pure letters
3. Reject any symbols
4. Accept ONLY Alphanumeric combo
5. MUST be equal to 10 characters total

Here is what I have made and the problems with each:

1. `^(?!^\d*$)[a-zA-Z\d]{10}$`

   - This fails criteria #2
2. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$`

   - This fails criteria #1

I have tried some others that meet all criteria but fail the 10 char limit.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it ok to apply multiple regexes? You could use option #2 but then also check afterwards that it has at least one digit and at least one letter.

Comment: There is nothing that stops you from using a second lookahead: `^(?!\d+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)[a-zA-Z\d]{10}$`

Comment: @TylerMarshall In this case it had to be a single regex which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a second lookahead:

```
^(?!\d+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)[a-zA-Z\d]{10}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmITd0/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!%5Cd%2B%24)(%3F!%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%24)%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cd%5D%7B10%7D%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d+$)` - a negative lookahead that makes sure the whole string is not composed of just digits
- `(?![a-zA-Z]+$)` - the whole string cannot be all letters
- `[a-zA-Z\d]{10}` - 10 letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?=^.{10}$)^([a-z]+\d[a-z0-9]*|\d+[a-z][a-z0-9]*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TVQ8Nc/1)

#### Explanation:

```
(?=^.{10}$)^([a-z]+\d[a-z0-9]*|\d+[a-z][a-z0-9]*)$
(?=^.{10}$)                                         # there's exactly 10 characters following
           ^(                 |                 )$  # we match the entire string, containing either:
             [a-z]+\d[a-z0-9]*                      # letters, followed by a number, followed by alphanumerics, or
                               \d+[a-z][a-z0-9]*    # numbers, followed by a letter, followed by alphanumerics
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lookahead to find at least one char of each type you require, and specify the length and char limitation in the "regular" part of your regex:

`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z]{10}$`

- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`- Look ahead and find a letter,
- `(?=.*\d)` - Look ahead and find a digit
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]{10}` - exactly 10 digit/letter chars